# regex: find text inbetween space and specifictext which is filled with nonspace variable text inbetween

Tags: regex

I have the following case

```
kjhasd jh asdkhj jh skdj kjas dkjh XXXXXXXXENDoasd kjha sdkj asdkjh
```

Here `XXXXXXXX` is a variable text(without any spaces) but will have a space before it.
SO i want to find the text `XXXXXXXXEND` how to do using regex

I have tried  `.*END`

It will find  `jh asdkhj jh skdj kjas dkjh XXXXXXXXEND`

which i dont want. i only want `XXXXXXXXEND`

Also kindly Note the text "kjhasd jh asdkhj jh skdj kjas dkjh: before `XXXXXXXXEND` is also not a fixed text, it also keeps varying. And also text after `XXXXXXXXEND` also keeps varying.

Its the pattern `space + (no space text) + END` this is what i want to find.

Because I have so many line and this keeps repeating. So using regex i can manipulate them easily.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: sorry. I have put what i have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there will be a space before the part you want to match, your regex should start by finding a space, then a bunch of non-spaces, then `END`:

```
 \S*END
```

Note the initial space.

If you don't want to match the space and just the `XXXX` part, then you could use  a lookbehind:

```
(?<= )\S*END
```

though this is not supported in JavaScript

Comment: brilliant answer (Note the initial space - it was not working i thought but this note helped me)